# How to get the value property of an element using querySelector

Tags: javascript

I am a newbie when it comes to JavaScript. I just made some practice projects to further sharpen my knowledge.

How do i get the value property of and element using ID?

This one seems to work :

```
var billAmount = document.getElementById("billamt").value;
```

But i wanted to use the querySelector method instead of getElementById.
Whats the best and proper way to do it?

so far i have tried the code below but did not work :

```
var billAmount = document.querySelector("#billamt").value;
```

```js
const billamt = document.querySelector('#billamt').value;

function calculate() {
  console.log(billamt * 0.25);
}
```

```html
<label>How much did you pay?
  <input id="billamt" type="text" placeholder="Bill Amount">
</label>
<button onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button>
```

you may view the whole source code of the project via this link :
https://codepen.io/anthony-bahinting/pen/dybegMW

Comment: Please post a [MCVE] in the question itself. `document.getElementById("billamt").value;` to `document.querySelector("#billamt").value` should work just fine

Comment: Anthony make sure you spelled your ID correctly and included the '#'.  Also, your demo works as expected.

Comment: The codepen seems to work fine, what's the problem?

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: @Barmar its now working even in codepen. i tried var billAmount = document.querySelector("#billamt").value; and then console log billAmount but it shows Nan

Comment: @DanielA.White I am using chrome

Comment: Because later in the code you use `billAmount.value`, but you set `billAmount` to the value rather than the element.

Comment: Compare how you set `billAmount` to how you set `serviceType`.

Comment: @Barmar just disregard the other codes (billAmount.value) . what i am trying to achieve is that it should console.log billAmount if var billAmount = document.querySelector("#billamt").value; is declared

Comment: Please use a code snippet with a minimal complete example. Links to a CodePen are fine but if you're editing it at the same time, it's a moving target for the people trying to help you.

Comment: @stealththeninja sorry about that and thank you for the info. I'm new here as well :) i will check on that

Comment: You're getting the value before the user has entered anything into the amount field.

Comment: It was correct before you edited it. You set `billAmount = document.querySelector("#billamt")` at the beginning, and then when the user asks to calculate the tip you get the value with `billAmount.value`.

Comment: @Barmar now that make sense :)

Comment: When I put the declaration inside the calculate function instead of declaring it on top globally, it works! so yeah you are right its not within the scope when the value was inputed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code evaluates the value of `#billamt` immediately, no value has been given by the user yet. Instead, save a reference to the element and ask for its value when you run your `calculate()` method.

```js
const billamtElem = document.querySelector('#billamt'); // HTMLElement

function calculate() {
  console.log(billamtElem.value * 0.25);
}
```

```html
<label>How much did you pay?
  <input id="billamt" type="text" placeholder="Bill Amount">
<label>
<button onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button>
```

Comment: so decalring it as const billAmtElem = document.querySelector('#billamt').value; wont work?

Comment: but i have tried const billAmtElem = getElementById('billamt').value; and it did work

Comment: No, it won't work. The value is an empty string when you're evaluating it. By saving a reference to the element, you can ask for its value at calculation time.

Comment: @Anthony You're confusing the element with the element's value.

Comment: When I put the declaration inside the calculate function instead of declaring it on top globally, it works! so yeah you are right its not within the scope when the value was inputed.

Comment: @Anthony It's not a matter of scope, it's a matter of timing. You have to get the value AFTER the value is set by the user.

Comment: Yeah timing makes more sense :)

Comment: Well thanks for the input. There's so much more to learn from here hehehe